# How to use CSS to style a descendant (not a direct child) of an element?

Tags: css, html-table, hbox

I am trying to override the style of a descendant (not the direct child) of an element using CSS.

Say, I am working on:

```
<table id="z_d__h3-real" class="z-hbox">
 <tbody>
   <tr valign="top">
   -----
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to override the style to set the valign of the tr element to "center".

I tried doing:

```
table.z-hbox tr {
    vertical-align:center;
}
```

This doesn't work though. I assume table.z-hbox tr is looking up for a direct child `<tr>` which is not the case here. As `<tr>` is wrapped inside `<tbody>`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the precedence. I figured out that it should be

**vertical-align: middle** instead of vertical-align: center

This works.

Answer (score 2):

Inline styles have higher priority than those defined in  tags or a stylesheet include. Either remove the `valign="top"` attribute (it's deprecated in newer versions of the HTML standard anyway), or, if you cannot change the markup, mark the CSS rule as `!important`. The selector itself is good (you can test this by adding other rules).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is fine. Whitespace between selectors selects descendants, `>` would be needed for direct children.

Your problem is that the inline attribute takes precedence over the style in the stylesheet. You could try using `!important`, but I don't honestly know how precedence works with deprecated HTML attributes. I never use them.